# Email Schema Markup

Tags: google-schemas

I am currently experimenting with some [Rental Car Reservation Email Schema](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/rental-car) and also [Go-To Action Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/actions-overview). About a year ago, I played around with the code and used [Apps Script Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial) to test the markup. The tests worked as expected and I was getting all sort of great results in email. Specifically, I was seeing action buttons and, when in Google Inbox, all sorts of cool treatments of the reservations. I also saw my tests come through on "my car rental" queries in Google.

Today, I went ahead and redid my test, and some of the results were not the same. First off, I am unable to replicate the action buttons. My theory is that perhaps these were discontinued with the new version of Gmail. As for Google Inbox, those are still coming through. However, with Google Inbox slated to be discontinued in March 2019, this matters very little to us now. Lastly, my "my car rental" queries are not pulling in any results.

Is anyone able to confirm that email markup is still relevant? Google's documentation hasn't been updated since 2017, so it would be great to know before going through the effort of implementing the markup.

Thanks!